# Why don't schools cover debuggers?

Tags: education, language-agnostic, debugging

After yet another homework [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312182/reading-data-from-file-into-2-arrays) on SO.  It seems like that vast majority of students have no idea what a debugger is or how to use one.  I feel that knowing how to use a debugger is almost as important as other fundamental of programming.

- The question is shouldn't debugging and how to use modern debugging tools be taught alongside programming fundamentals?  If not why not.

Comment: Erm.. you're saying gdb is a *modern* debugging tool? It's not a bad debugger, but it's certainly not state of the art.

Comment: I would Agree but I have also answered question were students use visual studio and didn't know how or why they would use a debugger.

Comment: @rerun: Erm.. ouch. They can't hit the "play" button on the IDE? (BTW, I +1'd)

Comment: system.out print logging is the last bastion of the lazy and inept

Comment: @Jarrod, a pretty broad generalization and perhaps overly so.  Sometimes you simply cannot use a debugger on your program where the problem occurs.

Comment: I was taught how to use a debugger in my first-year CS sequence, and have frequently used them throughout my education and work. I find it difficult to believe that places don't teach how to use them, but find it more likely that the student doesn't see the advantages and therefore doesn't learn.

Comment: @Jarrod Not true, this can be the only way to diagnose a bug in the release build.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson, one have to resort to an interactive debugger *only*  after all the other options had been exhausted. Interactive debugging (like in gdb and visual studio) is mostly suitable for post-mortem examination when you already have an idea on where, roughly, the problem can be. An initial identification of a problem is better done with proper assertions, contracts and debug logging.

Comment: I have had applications run for years in production servicing millions of unique users a day, and millions of transactions an hour with zero downtime and never had to resort to any logging in production. Production server logs should only output 2 things. "[timestamp] application started" and "[timestamp] application stopped"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not so much the case that the use of *debuggers* that needs to be taught, but the more general techniques of *debugging*. This would include teaching how to use a debugger of course but would also various other important techniques, e.g.

- critical thinking
- divide and conquer
- printf debugging, logging, etc
- desk checking
- stress testing

As an additional benefit, many of the techniques can also be applied to problem-solving in areas other than programming.

There's quite a good book on this whole subject, which should probably be required reading for all undergraduates and anyone learning the basics of programming: [*Debugging* by David J Agans](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0814474578).

Answer (score 8):

Tertiary computer science courses are tailored towards teaching students *programming fundamentals*, as you've mentioned - these concepts are taught to the students in hope that they would grok the *necessary* concepts and apply it to a wider range of programming languages and problem sets.

Debugging tools, on the other hand, are a subset in the *implementation* area - each tool is different for each language (even though the concepts are the same). We were exposed to debugging tools but never really covered them in depth. If we spent more than a week on debugging tools, I would look back - in hindsight - and deem that a waste of time. I'd rather learn about BigO notation or polymorphism. However, ff the power of a debugging tool has not been (successfully) conveyed to the students, then that would be an absent necessity.

Comment: +1. Translated: Because not everybody uses MSVS, GCC/GDB, LLVM/CLANG, etc.

Comment: +1 although I have to admit I agree with @rerun; A course (or part of one) that goes over basic concepts and tools that are used in a software shop would go a long way towards getting new graduates productive.  I've run across several that didn't seem to understand source control even after using it for a while.

Comment: many of the Skills that average developers spend alot of there time with are covered in school.  Source Control, Configuration management in general, code exploration, code reading, Build processes etc etc.  While I understand that CS degrees need to cover the theoretical aspects I think one senor level class where students worked with a large existing code base find and fix bugs and get it checked in code and "deployed" would make a new developer a lot more useful.

Comment: I totally disagree. If actual code is being written (because writing code is a good way of practising the scientific concepts), then students should have access to *good* ways of writing that code, and that includes making use of a debugger if so needed. That's not taking away time that could be spend on bigO notation - it is freeing up time that many students spend on bruteforcing their way through minor errors. Nothing much is gained from that. Besides, many other science courses (physics for example) do include practical measurement skills as part of their curriculum.

Comment: Using a debugger requires understanding how the computer works, not just the code. I'd consider this a *programming fundamental*.  I've encountered too many students who just have no idea what their computer is actually doing, and that does not make for a good programmer.

Comment: @Ken: We have a "Software Engineering" class at my school which, from what I've heard, does pretty much that (http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Courses/Data/209.html). The surprising thing, perhaps, is that quite a few of the people I talked to found it to be one of the _less_ useful classes: apparently more or less everything taught there can be picked up by working on your own (largish) projects. Of course, for students that do not want to work on projects like that on their own, this course is probably more useful.

Answer (score 2):

In most introductory programming courses program state is simple enough that you can weed out any bugs with a few print statements. There also might be the issue of forcing students to do things by hand so they get a sense of how and where in the code certain types of bugs occur. If you have no idea where to look then a debugger is going to be pretty useless.

Comment: A good debugger is *easier* to use than print statements. Print statements require that you somehow have a way to serialize your data into a string, which necessitates it's own (possibly bug ridden) code to do the serialization. For example, a linked list program is easy to step through in a debugger, but print statements aren't going to help a student who's trying to write   linked list transversal algorithm -- because you'd need that algorithm to write the right print statements.

Comment: @Billy so stepping through the wrong code is somehow going to help them?

Comment: @Neil: If they don't know why that code is wrong, yes.

Comment: @Billy: I'm not sure how a debugger is going to help you if you don't know how to traverse a linked list and are trying to use the debugger to figure out the proper traversal code. The debugger is not magic and it's not going to help you write a while loop.

Comment: @davidk01 But it can show you where you deference a null.

Comment: @Billy: Not if we use your logic. You've been arguing all this time that the student wasn't even able to get started with the traversal code let alone dereferencing issues.

Comment: @davidk: 1. I think you meant to reply to @rerun. 2. I don't understand your point. Being able to see the data structure in memory is useful for writing your code, even if your code is wrong.

Comment: @Billy: 1. Right. 2. So does being able to print values without stepping through the code with a debugger. Also, this thread has gotten off track so I'm done since any further discussion is likely to stray even further.

Comment: @Billi ONeal, you're wrong. A debugger you're talking about does not exist. Interactive stepping through the program is only useful when you've already identified the problem with debug logging. Never in my practice (>20yrs) I had to use a debugger with my own code - proper assertions and logging were always sufficient. I'm only using that damned tools with the libraries code and the legacy stuff. And, btw., being able to serialise *any*  data structure into something readable is *always*  a good idea. Some languages/environments gives this for free.

Comment: @SK: 1. But sometimes they don't do that for free. I'm not saying that it's a bad idea to always have serialization code, but to somebody **new** who doesn't even know what the memory structure looks like, writing the serialization stuff is going to be as hard or harder than the original code. 2. What do you mean that debugger does not exist? I'm not even talking about the "step through line by line" bit -- I'm talking about the "see the contents of memory pointed to by this pointer" bit -- and most all debuggers have that feature.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, how would you browse a memory of a microcontroller device, attached to a serial port? And, I believe that it is not such a good idea to expose freshers to the low level languages with pointers and stuff before they're literate enough in data structures and algorithms. By that time they'll know how to debug properly.

Comment: @SK: I don't think most new programmers are looking at memory of microcontroller devices. I'm talking about someone learning C on any plain old PC. Obviously if no good debugger exists for the platform you're using then you can't use a debugger. However, if a good debugger does exist for your programming environment it can be quite helpful.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, sorry, I thought you're answering to two different messages. By "that debugger does not exist" I meant that there is no debugger which makes debugging easier than print statements. It have not been invented yet.

Comment: @SK-logic: I don't understand. How is having to write serialization code less difficult than hovering your pointer over a variable you want to examine?

Comment: @Billy ONeal, the most difficult part is in identifying the right moment when to either inspect a value in a debuger (btw., in most cases it is still something like calling a .dump() method, not a direct memory inspection) or to print a serialised value. With a proper debug logging infrastructure in place the problem is narrowed down to an analysis of log files. In most cases a simple `grep` does the job. No stepping, no conditional breakpoints - just grep.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so important. I almost never use one, and never have. The best way to debug code is:

- don't write the bugs in the first place
- if you do write them, fix them by thinking, not by diving in to the debugger

And for much modern, multi-threaded software, debuggers have the effect of hiding bugs rather than uncovering them. And they should definitely not be "taught" at degree level, any more than one would teach how to use a word processor.

Comment: I think this one depends. If you're trying to get used to the behavior of a large and poorly documented codebase you didn't write, a debugger is one of the fastest ways to get acclimated with what the codebase is doing. If you're writing all the code, sure, you won't need a debugger often, but not all of us are in that place. +1

Comment: @Billy We must agree to differ. You try getting to know a huge MT trading server with a debugger.

Comment: @Neil: I've never personally dealt with that kind of thing... but I have debugged MT code before without problems. Perhaps I'm spoiled by MSVC++ -- the debuggers there make showing what the various threads are doing really easy. But if I was debugging in versions prior to 2008 (I think that's when that was added) I could see how that could make things more difficult.

Comment: @Neil: Don't get me wrong -- I'm not saying the debugger is a substitute for thinking, or that it should be the only thing you look at. I'm just saying it's a tool which in some cases can make understanding something easier. If a debugger is causing more confusion, it's generally easy to tell that it's causing more confusion (Because you're getting more confused), and that's when you turn off the debugger and try something else. It's helpful in some cases, but it's no substitute for looking at code/input/output and thinking about what's going on.

Comment: I know you are flying the face of received wisdom around here.  But you are in good company with people like Linus Torvalds, Larry Wall, Brian Kernighan and Rob Pike.

Comment: @btilly: Linus, Brian, and Rob are all Kernel developers. In the kernel, I agree a debugger is generally worthless -- most kernel debuggers are garbage. Larry is... well... let's just say Larry's the guy who brought a language into the world which has over 100 **operators**. ;)

Comment: @Neil: This approach makes sense for very smart people.  That description does not apply to everybody (most people?) in the industry at all times.

Comment: Oddly enough, when I went through college, the CS majors had to take a class that covered word processors.  (It was generally considered worthless, but the university did require it.)

Comment: @Billy ONeal: It is easy to mock Perl 6.  But Larry Wall invented a bunch of other stuff, including patch, and was on board the unit testing train 25 years ago - long, long, long before the benefits were widely understood.  More importantly, Larry Wall uses a very macro-heavy programming style.  Macros and debuggers are generally not friends.  Neither are closures and debuggers.  If you venture into those styles, the debugger quickly becomes less useful.

Comment: @btilly: C#'s debugger handles closures just fine. My point about Larry Wall is not to say that he's not smart -- he is smart. My point was that he is not the general population.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging should be taught because students are humans and humans make all kinds of mistakes, some of which require acquiring some experimental data (debugging info) before any enlightenment regarding a given mistake occurs.

Debugging isn't taught because of the premise (maybe inherited from math department) that programs should be correct by design, perhaps even provably so.  And thus students shouldn't be "experimenting" with programming correctly.  However this ignores the real world manufacturing process of imperfect humans cranking out software to changing specs under schedule pressures & etc.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe my school is just different, but that's not how things are done at CWRU.

Comment: Probably depends on the historical department inheritance tree of the programming course in question.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting all this. All introductory classes spend a few lectures on how to track down bugs.

Comment: @davidk01 - That doesn't explain the OP's observation, which I've heard, not frequently, but more than once before.

Comment: @hotpaw2: What doesn't explain the OP's observation? Just because students have a hard time learning to debug programs doesn't mean it is not taught which is the conclusion you're jumping to. I've take several programming courses both as an undergraduate student and as a graduate student. In every class the instructor has spent at least one lecture to go over an incorrect program and to fix it in order to demonstrate some common debugging techniques.

Comment: @davidk01: none of my introductory classes did.

Comment: "Debugging isn't taught because of the premise (maybe inherited from math department) that programs should be correct by design". Does this also mean that secure programming is not taught because professors assume that everybody writes secure code naturally?

Comment: @faif : I wasn't taught either secure programming or debugger use.  Both were rather difficult when submitting a Fortran punched card deck with a 1 to 2 hour turnaround.  I did learn something about reading core dumps.

Answer (score 0):

This question is foreign to me. At my university the use of the debugger (JDB and the Eclipse debugger) were taught as early as the first-year computer science sequence. The use of debuggers and other testing tools were taught again in the course on software testing.

I personally find it incredibly difficult to believe that any good school that is attempting to prepare people for entry into the workforce isn't teaching about proper debugging and testing techniques. They obviously can't cover all aspects of it, but they can at least teach the basics in the classroom.

Answer (score 0):

**Figure it out on your own**

I didn't need and didn't want a professor or T.A. to take time teaching me something I could **easily** figure out on my own.  They are there to teach me the hard concepts and guide learning.  They aren't and **should not** be there so you don't have to RTFM.

**Learn How To Learn**

College should be about learning how to learn, not just having your hand held through every topic you don't know.  If you have your hand held constantly through this process you will fail miserably in the real world.

**Uphill, Both Ways, Through the Snow**

When I went to school they didn't bother to teach you the language either.  You were expected to pick it up on your own time.  They would give you the project and facilities.  It was up to you to track down the information you needed in order to complete the implementation and submit a working program.  Pretty similar to the real world, except with office hours.